# Are there a way of preventing automatic exception handling?

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

If the user enter a non-numeric value for example "Hello", I want to give the user a new chance to enter a numeric value until he succeeds.

Running the code below, the text "This is not a numeric value. Enter a numeric value: ", will show in the console, if the user enters a non-numeric value. However, the user will not be able to enter a new value. Because the error message "Exception in thread..." will show and stop the program.

How do I solve this?

**Edit!**
New code (This code works, **except** it stops the program completely. Every method called afterwards, won't run.) **Edit2!** It did not work!

```
int number;

do {
  try {
    System.out.println("Enter a numeric value: ");
    number = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());

    if (s.nextInt() != (int)number) {
      throw new NumberFormatException();
    }
    break;
  }
  catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("This is not a numeric value. Enter a numeric value: ");
  }
} while (true)
```

Old code

```
int number;

try {
  Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

  System.out.println("Enter a numeric value: ");
  number = s.nextInt();

  if (number != (int)number) {
    throw new Exception();
  }
}
catch(Exception e) {
  do {
    System.out.println("This is not a numeric value. Enter a numeric value: ");
    number = s.nextInt();
  } while (number != (int)number);
}
```

Comment: You have a do-while loop inside your catch block. Where else could you move that loop to in order to continuously prompt the user for input while simultaneously catching non-numeric inputs?

Comment: The check `number != (int)number` is meaningless, since `number` is an `int`. You won't get to that line if your input is not an `int.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 2):

Use NumberFormatException instead of Base Exception Class

```
int number;
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a numeric value: ");

do {
    try {

        number = Integer.parseInt(s.nextLine());
        //Do your work
        break;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("This is not a numeric value. Enter a numeric value: ");

    }
}
while (true);

}
```

Comment: This did solve the problem I displayed. However, it completely stops the program. Any methods called afterwards don't run. Do you have a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Please try below given code:

```
int number;
Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
  System.out.println ("Enter a numeric value: ");

do
  {
try
{

  number = Integer.parseInt (s.nextLine ());
  //Do your work
  break;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
  System.out.println
    ("This is not a numeric value. Enter a numeric value: ");

}
  }
while (true);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to loop forever until the user enters a valid integer. A common way to express "loop forever" is with `while (true) {...}`. This is an "infinite loop." The only way to exit this loop is with a `break` statement or a `return` statement (or by throwing an exception, but in this case you want to ***catch*** the exception and continue looping).

One problem with using `scanner.nextInt()` is that if the value is not an integer, the value will remain in the scanner's buffer. If you keep calling `nextInt()`, you'll just keep getting `InputMismatchException`s since the scanner will keep trying to interpret the same bad input as an integer, over and over again.

One way around that problem is to use `scanner.nextLine()` to read the value as a String, and then use `Integer.parseInt(String)` to convert the `String` to an `int`. If the conversion fails, `Integer.parseInt(String)` throws a `NumberFormatException`. You can handle this exception by catching it.

Here's a little function that loops forever until the user enters a value that can be parsed as an `int`:

```
public static int promptForInt(Scanner scanner) {
  while (true) {
    System.out.println("Enter a numeric value:");
    try {
      return Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      System.out.print("This is not a numeric value. ");    
    }
  }
}
```

You can call the method like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int number = promptForInt(scanner);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you truly understand where the exception is coming from.  The line `throw new Exception();` ***never runs*** in your code.  This is because your if statement says `if (number != (int) number)`, which will never be true because the variable `number` is already of the type `int`, so you are basically saying `if (number != number)`, which can never be true.  If you take a look at Scanner's `nextInt()` method, you'll notice that it actually throws `InputMismatchException`.  That is the exception you are catching with your try-catch, but it is not the exception that is causing the error message.  So where is that exception coming from?  The line `number = s.nextInt();` is not compilable code.  You defined `s` inside the try block, so therefore `s` **only exists *inside* the try block**.  You get an exception when you try to access it in the catch block because `s` is not a variable there; it does not exist as far as the compiler is concerned.  The fix is pretty simple; just move the declaration for `s` to outside the try block, and put the while loop around the try-catch block.  Also remember to consume the line separators in the input stream using `s.nextLine()` every time you try to read an int.  Here's an example of how I would do it:

```
int number;
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in); //declare s outside of the try block

System.out.println("Enter a numeric value: ");

while (true) { //while loop goes around the try-catch block
  try {
    number = s.nextInt(); //this could throw InputMismatchException
    break; //if no exception is thrown, break out of the loop
  } catch (InputMismatchException e) { //if the exception is thrown
    s.nextLine(); //consume the line separator character(s)
    System.out.println("This is not a numeric value. Enter a numeric value: "); //prompt the user for another value
    //this will then go back to the top of the try block again, because we never broke out of the while loop
  }
}

s.nextLine(); //consume the line separator character(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, if you take your input as a string you can parseInt to check if its an integer value

```
    String number = null;

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a numeric value: ");
    number = s.next();

    try {
        // checking valid integer using parseInt() method
        Integer.parseInt(number);

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("This is not a numeric value. Enter a numeric value:");
        number = s.next();

        // put this line here to prove it accepted the second attempt
        System.out.println("Your entered integer is:" + number);
    }
    s.close();

}
```

}